# How to work with spring annotations in large applications?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

If you are starting a Spring project, you may know where you have placed the `@controller, @requestmapping` annotations and other annotations and the corresponding `controller class`.

Lets say few months down the  line a new developer comes into your team, how would he figure out which classes to work with? Because unlike the `xml` based approach where all the configurations is centrally located in an `config.xml` file, we don't have nothing of that sort with annotation as per my knowledge (I am new to spring), we write the respective annotations in a class itself.

Comment: It's supposed a new developer must start coding without reading any information neither receiving a brief explanation on the project he is joining?

Comment: @jlumietu  lets say the lead has asked the really Jr developer to perform a task A. and he has been told to take task B(which is already configured or working) as a reference to perform task A.In an xml file it is easy to find out where and how the task B is configure and the controller classes etc associated with it.

Comment: But the any member of the team, including any newbie JR developer must have an idea of how is the package structure defined. Or at least, just know where is the main configuration class and the packages to scan, nope? Just as with xml config, anybody should have where to find the application-context.xml or the spring-servlet, or  if somebody does not know where, at least should know whom to ask for help... It's more related to project management than software architecture I think

Comment: @jlumietu application-context.xml is easy to find.You will be surprised, there are so many start ups who ask you to straight away debug code (back end of jsp or html) without explaining anything from day 1.I know its not a good practice.In that case, if the lead asks you to modify a jsp the corresponding controller class, its easy to navigate through XML based approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring, **two ways** to define your configuration :

- Either in a XML file or
- Java class

So just like `xml`, in Java also you need to create a `configuration class` which will have all the required configurations details. You can define all of your beans, filters etc here.

For example , You create a configuration class **`MvcConfig`** with the below annotations

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.example"})
```

Now your `base package is com.abc.example`. In all the applications, the best practice is to keep all of you `controller\service\DAO classes` in specific packages like

```
    Controller : com.abc.example.controller,
    Service : com.abc.example.service,
    DAO : com.abc.example.dao
```

So anybody who comes in will know where are all the respective classes located and from where to start.

Example **`configuration class`** :

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.abc.example"})
    public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```